# reading lines of text in a nonblocking way

Tags: c, file-descriptor

In a C program I want to read text lines from stdin.
At the same time I want to handle data coming from another file descriptor.

I tried to use `poll` to wait for any of the two source to become readable and handle them accordingly. However poll needs bare file descriptors and for reading whole lines with something like `fgets` I need a FILE handle.

I can use `fileno` or `fdopen` to "convert" them, but using both in a mixed way does not seem to be a good idea.

Therefore, is there a good way to wait for lines of text without blocking or threading?

Comment: Why not use system calls like `read()` to read from stdin?

Comment: `read` is not easily able to read until end of line. This would mean I would need to implement my own buffering infrastructure similar to FILE.

Comment: `fdopen` looks the correct way to me. Did you try it ?

Comment: Note, that when `poll()` returns because `stdin` has more data it doesn't mean that there is whole line and `fgets()` won't block.

Comment: You should use your own `fgets()` that will return something like `EAGAIN` if there is no complete line on `stdin`.

Comment: @Serhio, That is probably the best solution. Please write an answer to allow me accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you want for multiplexing (`select()`, `poll()`, `epoll_wait()`). But you shouldn't read from `stdin` with `fgets()` because multiplexing knows nothing about if we've got complete line or no. So it may block in some cases. You should write custom line reading function, that will indicate that there is no complete line yet and return immediately.